# My app went from "has one or more issues" to "completed processing" without me touching it. What caused the change?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store

When I initially tried to submit my app for review in the IOS store, I immediately I received an email saying I had one or more issues with my app.  Approximately 10 minutes later, I received another email saying that app has completed processing.  I did nothing to change anything in the 10 minutes that elapsed.

I went back to the drawing board and built another version of my app and submitted that about 3 hours later.  Only to receive the same rejection response, followed by a "completed processing" email.

Because I wasn't aware of that my initial app completed processing, I ended up using the second version that I created.  I was able to submit that version of the app for review.

Here is a screenshot of the initial "issues" email.
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the completed processing email for the same app that was submitted just 10 minutes prior.

[image]

Since it happened twice in almost the same exact fashion, I believe that it's something on Apple's side.  Any ideas how/why this happened or does anyone have experience initially have their app rejected and then 10 minutes later completing the process?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question for Apple support, not a question that can be answered by Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

From the first screenshot I can see apple review team has rejected app due to push notification issue.

So resolve it here few things you will need to take care of before submitting new binary :

- Make sure your app is using push notification or not
- If its not using than disable push notification from APP Id from developer account
- Lets say if your app using push notification than make sure its properly enabled on your App Id on developer account & also have proper certificate attached from Push notification distribution
- Also make sure that certificate is installed on your system keychain
- Go to targets -> Capabilities & switch on Push notification

[image]

- Now at last make sure you have Push notification frameworks & methods imported properly in to application & its checking the permission alert

Once this all things done than you are good to go with submitting new App version.

**Important Note :**

- Before submitting new version keep Add review note for review team that new have done changes with the push notification issue & now it works fine so Kindly get us approval quickly as possible

Hope it helps.